# Force user to declare object const

Tags: c++

Is there a way to force the user of a class to construct `const` objects based on data used for the constructor?

For example, consider a small wrapper class around some buffer that can be `const` or non-`const`

```
class Wrapper {
  public:
    Wrapper(const char*);
    Wrapper(char*);
};
```

Now if the user is supplying a `const`, can I force them to declare the object to be `const` on compile time. That is

```
// you have to do this if the input is const 
const char* a; 
// this will not compile 
Wrapper w(a); 
// but this will 
const Wrapper(a);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: With a factory (function), I think there is a way (binding to a const ref).

Comment: Why not use an immutable wrapper? I.e. a wrapper that does not allow changes to the wrapped object.

Comment: To me the "obvious" thing to do is to write two classes, `ConstWrapper` and `Wrapper`. Make `ConstWrapper` behave as immutable and give it both ctors. `Wrapper` allows mutation, but omits the `const char*` ctor. To keep things interesting, derive `Wrapper` from `ConstWrapper` -- then a `Wrapper` is convertible to `ConstWrapper` assuming the type is copyable, and you can write functions that accept `ConstWrapper&`, and pass them a reference to a `Wrapper`. Be careful, though, it might be better to have `ConstWrapper` and `Wrapper` both derive from `NonModifyingWrapper`.

Comment: I want the class to be useable for other purposes too. For example, I want to be able to create my Wrapper(my_data) and modify away. But, if someone gives me const data, I want to make sure that they don't modify it. Any non-const functions should be disabled.. I wonder if th ere is something with the new std about this

Comment: @bendervader: if you don't need to pass the wrappers around by exact type then another option is to write a class template `Wrapper<T>`, and a helper function `Wrapper<T> make_wrapper(T *ptr) { return Wrapper<T>(ptr); }`. Then the user writes `auto mywrapper = make_wrapper(ptr);`, and they get a `Wrapper<const char>` if they pass in a pointer-to-const and a `Wrapper<char>` otherwise. It should be easy to write the non-const functions such that they'll just fail when `T` is `const char`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in the constructor but you can create a factory that returns const objects refs or pointers.  However you will need to disable copy and copy construction and may not provide any value.

Comment: I found the same answer, implemented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46070617/225186